# HTTP-POST returns 400 when posting a value from the sensor

Tags: http, datalogging

I'm trying to POST the data of `total`, but it returns 400. but when I try a sample data like

`int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"amount\":\"total\"}");` (400)

into

`int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"amount\":\"15\"}");` it works (201).

How to make it work? Thanks!

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const byte interruptPin = 4;
const int interval = 500;
volatile unsigned long tiptime = millis();
volatile float rainrate = 0.3;
volatile float total;
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR count();

void loop() {
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if (WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED) {
      HTTPClient http;
      
      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(serverName);

      // Specify content-type header
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

      // Data to send with HTTP POST
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"amount\":\"total\"}");

      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        
      // Free resources
      http.end();
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}

void count() {
  // Grab the current ms count for common calculations
  unsigned long curtime = millis();
  
  // Make sure we don't record bounces
  if ((curtime - tiptime) < interval) {
    return;
  }

  // How long since the last tip?
  unsigned long tipcount = curtime - tiptime;
  tiptime = curtime;

  total += rainrate;
  Serial.println(total);
}
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, would you please try to serial output the exact strings that are sent in both cases to maybe find what's the important difference between them? You can post the results as edit to your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your line

```cpp
int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"amount\":\"total\"}");
```

is not doing what you think it's doing. You're not placing the contents of the variable called `total` in the string, you're placing the *word* `total` in the string.

Instead you need to build up the string from components before sending. I'd use something like:

```cpp
char temp[32];
snprintf(temp, 32, "{\"amount\":\"%.2f\"}", total);
int httpResponseCode = http.POST(temp);
```

That is assuming the `http.POST()` function will take a `char *` parameter. If not you may need to resort to a `String`:

```cpp
String temp = "{\"amount\":\"";
temp += String(total, 2);
temp += "\"}";
```

However it is best to avoid `String` as it can cause heap fragmentation causing your code to become unstable over time.

Comment: Note that his `total` is a `float`, so the format should have `%f` or `%g`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet So it is...

Comment: If you're going to go the `sprintf` route, it would be better to use `snprintf`:  `char temp[32]; snprintf(temp, sizeof temp, "{`.  Reasons to use the old non-n version are few and far between.

Comment: I was going to but couldn't remember off hand the order of the first two arguments.

Comment: Thanks! it worked :)